# RabbitMQ Python Producer and Consumer Microservice

Tags: python, architecture, rabbitmq, microservices

I've found numerous examples online of both Python RabbitMQ Consumers and Producers (as separate scripts). Is there a way to create  a single Python Microservice that is able to act as both a consumer and producer?

Comment: Consumer and Producer of what? This doesn't sound like term related to `Microservices` but more to `Message Queues`.

Comment: Yes, there is. I maintain the Pika library. If that's the one you are using, and you would like assistance, start a discussion [here](https://github.com/pika/pika/discussions) and share the code you have already tried via a git repository. The code *must* be runnable for me to dedicate time to assisting you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I remember having the same question many years ago. I use the Pika Library mentioned by Luke and have built a service mesh library on top of Pika, that's [recently been opensourced](https://github.com/robertbetts/nuropb). It maintains one connection to RabbitMQ, connects to multiple queues and handles many concurrent message flows. For example intra service or client to service request response and events. You're welcome to take a look to see how we built the RMQ transport layer.